# Pairs in poker. Faulty solution?

Tags: combinatorics, poker

An old question. How many different hands can you draw with one pair?

I have read an answer and explanation from [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223203/how-many-ways-to-make-a-pair-given-five-poker-cards) which i understand. What i don't understand is where i fail in my own logic.

For the first card, you can draw one of 52 cards. For the second, you can draw one of 3 cards in order to make a pair. The third card can be any of 48 cards to avoid 3 of a kind. Fourth card can be any of 44 cards to avoid 3 of a kind and two pair. Last card can be any of 40 cards to avoid 3 of a kind and two pair.

The answer should then be $52*3*48*44*40=13178880$ , but this is much larger than the actual answer.

Comment: The error here is that you treat the order of the cards as they are placed into your hand as being important and very specifically want the pair to appear as the first two cards.  This is in contrast to the number of hands where the pair could appear in any position in your hand and order of cards matters as well as in contrast to the number of hands where order of cards doesn't matter.

Comment: Your answer is off by a factor of $10$ for the number of hands with one pair where order of cards matters ($131788800$) and that answer is off by a factor of $1/5!=1/120$ for where order of cards doesn't matter ($131788800/120 = 1098240 = \binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3$)

Comment: To explain the above ($\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3$), choose one of 13 kinds (from 2, 3, ...,K), then choose two cards from the four of that kind (for example 2 jacks). Next choose three of the remaining 12 kinds and choose one of each of those kinds (there you get 4 choose 1 cubed).

Comment: It is not "wrong" per se to treat the order of the cards as being relevant, but you will find arithmetic and counting arguments to be much easier if you treat poker hands as being such that order of cards doesn't matter.  Whichever you happen to use, make sure to use the correct corresponding sample space if using for a probability calculation.  For five card hands this means to divide the number of hands of your desired type by $52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48$ if you chose that order matters and divide by $\binom{52}{5}$ if you chose that order doesn't matter.

Comment: you double counted pairs, you started off with any of the 52 cards, ace of hearts say, then you could choose one of 3, ace of diamonds say, but then you are going to count that again the other way around, you could also have choses ace of diamonds, then ace of hearts - then your last 3 cards, they can also be chosen if varying orders.

Comment: if you divide your answer by (2! 3!) you will then 'un double count' the pair and the remaining 3, and get an earlier answer